# Notifications when using Drupal with Zen 7.x-3.x and CTI Flex 7.x-1.0

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-zen

I get the following notification on many pages:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: jump_link_target in include() (line 74 of /Users/peter/dev/eyestreet.com/drupal/sites/default/themes/cti_flex/templates/html.tpl.php).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CTI Flex author is still working on compatibility with Zen 7.x - 3.x.  See http://drupal.org/node/1590214.  In the mean time, this hack seems to work:

Duplicate the line starting with `settings[zen_jump_link_target]` and change it to `settings[zen_skip_link_anchor]`.

In `themes/cti_flex/templates/html.tpl.php`, replace `$jump_link_target` with `$skip_link_anchor`.